# proof of limit identity using delta epsillon definition of the limit

Tags: calculus

For some reason I'm having quite a bit of troubling writing proofs with the delta epsilon definition of the limit.  Have a test coming up and this is a practice question.

Prove using the Epsillon Delta definition of the limit that $$ \lim_{x\to c} {f(x)} = \lim_{h\to 0} {f(c+h)}$$

Comment: Doesn't say, so I guess I'd have to assume that it is

Comment: What are the difficulties (be specific) you're facing in writing such proofs?  Include your answer, and any work you've done, as you edit your post.

Comment: Would you go to a doctor saying only "I hurt".  Then expect to have a diagnosis and treatment plan?  The doctor would be perfectly justified in asking you:  Where does it hurt?  How long has it hurt?  Has anything worked so far that brings you relief? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x)=L.   \hspace{5cm} (1)$

Let $\epsilon >0$. By $(1)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$.

Let $x = c + h$. Then $0<|h|<\delta \implies |f(c+h) - L| < \epsilon$.

This shows $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(c+h)=L$.

Comment: Awesome!  Was it necessary to let $\epsilon > 0$ in your second line?  Seems like that's already assumed when you assumed the limit

Comment: @johnfowles No, it is indeed a necessary statement.  Prior to its **introduction** in the second line, the variable $\epsilon$ does not even exist, so it is nonsense to claim that any assumption has been made about it.